# FreeBSD 11.2 passenger with nginx fails

Tags: passenger, freebsd

This affects FreeBSD 11.2 with nginx and the passenger module:

On firing up nginx I keep getting

nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog: it seems to have been killed with signal SIGABRT during startup (-1: Unknown error)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a serious problem with FreeBSD-nginx-passenger stack.

I dont't have a solution, but at least the problem is being discussed here:

https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2097

**Please do not delete this post, because there are really not many resources dealing with this passenger problem.**